# Uncaught ReferenceError: addtocart is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, shopping-cart

Currently I work in a shopping cart, I generated a small javascript code to send the data via POST to my cart, however I have problems since it does not load any product data.

I am working with codeigniter and its cart library and this is my code in my file view with my html and my javascript

```js
                   <script type="text/javascript">
    function addtocart(p_id)
    {
        var price = $('.valor'+p_id).attr('rel');
        var image = $('.imagen_portada'+p_id).attr('rel');
        var name  = $('.nombre'+p_id).text();
        var id    = $('.nombre'+p_id).attr('rel');
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('Emprendedor/add');?>",
                    data: "uuid="+id+"&imagen_portada="+image+"&nombre="+name+"&valor="+price,
                    
                    success: function (response) {
                       $(".cartcount").text(response);
                    }
                });
    }


  function opencart()
  {
      $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo site_url('Emprendedor/opencart');?>",
                  data: "",
                  success: function (response) {
                  $(".displaycontent").html(response);
                  }
              });
  }

</script>
```

```html
<div class="item active tab-pane fade active show" id="my-list">
                        <div class="row">
                            
                            
                            <?php
                            if(isset($publicaciones) && is_array($publicaciones) && count($publicaciones)){
                                $i=1;
                                foreach($publicaciones as $key=>  $producto){
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                                <div class="card h-100">
                                    
                                    
                                     <div class="card h-100 w-100" >
                                         <?php if ($producto["imagen_portada"] !="") { ?>
                                        <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/publicaciones/portadas/<?=$producto["imagen_portada"]?>" rel="<?= $producto['imagen_portada'] ?>" style="width: 20rem; height: 10rem;"  alt="Image" class="card-img-top img-fluid image<?php echo $producto['uuid'] ?>">
                                        <?php }else{ ?>
                                        <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/portadas/imagen-producto-no.jpeg" style="width: 20rem; height: 10rem;"  alt="Image" class="card-img-top img-fluid ">
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center p-3 m-0">
                                        <h4  class="name<?= $producto['uuid'] ?>" style="text-transform: uppercase;" rel="<?= $producto['uuid'] ?>"><?=$producto["nombre"]?></h4>
                                        <hr>
                                        <h3 style="color: #958A84" class="price<?php echo $producto['uuid'] ?>"> <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign" rel="<?= $producto['valor'] ?>"></i> <?=number_format($producto["valor"],0,',','.')?> CLP</h3>
                                        <div class="text-center mb-2">
                                        <!--<a  href="<?= base_url('cart/'.$producto['uuid']) ?>" class="btn v1"> Agregar al carrito  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></a> -->
                                        <button class="btn v1 btn-block" onclick="javascript:addtocart('<?php echo $producto['uuid'] ?>')">Agregar al carrito  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer text-muted p-1">
                                        <p style=" text-align: left; padding-left: 15px;"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> <?=$producto["tags"]?> </p>
                                      </div>
                                </div> 
                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            $i++;
                            }}
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
```

and this is my controller file to add the data in the cart, taken as a reference from the codeigniter documentation

```html
function add()
            {
            // Set array for send data.
            $insert_data = array(
                        'id' => $this->input->post('uuid'),
                        'name' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
                        'price' => $this->input->post('valor'),
                        'image' => $this->input->post('imagen_portada'),
                        'qty' => 1
                        );
            
            $this->cart->insert($insert_data);
            echo $fefe = count($this->cart->contents());
            
            }

            public function opencart()
                {
                    $data['cart']  = $this->cart->contents();
                    $this->load->view("comun/cart_modal", $data);
                }
```

I wanted to check that my data was reaching the data arrangement of my cart, and I noticed that it throws me this error that I cannot solve, indicating that the button that sends the id of my products is not defined in my javascript function.

Comment: Can you check and make sure that `addtocart()` function loaded after the button elements are added the page? Also try to call addtocart() without the "javascript:" in front of it

Comment: I already checked removing the **javascript:** before the **addtocart ()**  function, and the function does not load when calling it from the button since it throws the mentioned error that the function is not defined

Comment: Your second function's name is only `add()`. Is that done on purpose or it should be `addtocart()`?

Comment: It is on purpose, I did it so as not to confuse the controller function with that of the view, within the `addtocart()` function, I call this function through the line `url: "<? php echo site_url ('Emprendedor/add');?>",`

Comment: I am tempted to write a complete CodeReview, but alas I don't have the time.  Please draw some inspiration from the techniques in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/7156323/2943403 (I mean the question, not the answer) regarding pulling you styling out of your markup, and your js out of your markup.  I would use jquery event listeners instead of declaring functions.  You don't seem to be using a `<form>`, so I'd probably use `data-` attributes in the button and make a seialized json object from the `dataset()` to be used in the `$.post` process. Don't declare `$fefe`.